# Access date format

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble copying a date field from one table to another in Access, the date format in my tables is showing as 23/08/2019 (23rd August). Usually I pull data into a VB.NET application, process it then insert it back into the DB, when I do this I use a function to convert the date into American format 08/23/2019 and it  works fine, but I'm trying to copy the date into another table just using SQL and it puts it the wrong way around:

```
INSERT INTO Bets (rdate, track, horse, odds) 
SELECT rdate, track, horse, odds
FROM Selections;
```

This is odd as even though it shows the UK format in original table, it still works correctly, I.E. records with date 02/01/2019 would appear when selecting records for January 2019, but copying it to another table in this format makes it backwards.

Comment: Try using the conversion function here as well.

Comment: The conversion function is a VB function in my VB program, is there an SQL equivalent?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Access query objects can call custom VBA functions. So either process the query in VB or write a VBA function. Maybe process the SQL in VBA. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Access dates like all Office apps dates will align to the regional settings of whatever client machine it runs on. Are you saying the posted append query does not work correctly regarding dates? Is *rdate* being formatted prior to insert or your VB code formats *rdate* in *Selections* with a month-first date? Please post enough code to understand context.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to "convert".

You are mixing up the date *value* and the display *format*. The value is what matters, the format is for display only.

If you don't apply a specific format when listing the values, a default format is applied.